# QML alias: unable to find id using layer

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to make an alias of a ShaderEffect. However, when I do that:

```
Item {
    id: root;
    property color colorBackground: Qt.rgba(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
    property color colorStroke: Qt.rgba(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
    layer.enabled: true;

    layer.effect: ShaderEffect {
        property alias colorBackground: root.colorBackground;
        property alias colorStroke: root.colorStroke;

        fragmentShader: "
            uniform lowp sampler2D source; // This item
            uniform lowp float qt_Opacity; // Inherited opacity of this item
            uniform lowp vec4 colorBackground;
            varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
            void main() {
                lowp vec4 p = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0);
                lowp float g = dot(p.xyz, vec3(0.344, 0.5, 0.156));
                gl_FragColor = colorBackground;
            }";
    }
}
```

I get `Unable to find id root`

And when I do:

```
Item {
    property alias colorBackground: shaderEffect.colorBackground;
    property alias colorStroke: shaderEffect.colorStroke;
    layer.enabled: true;

    layer.effect: ShaderEffect {
        id: shaderEffect;
        property color colorBackground: Qt.rgba(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
        property color colorStroke: Qt.rgba(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
        fragmentShader: "
            uniform lowp sampler2D source; // This item
            uniform lowp float qt_Opacity; // Inherited opacity of this item
            uniform lowp vec4 color;
            varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
            void main() {
                lowp vec4 p = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0);
                lowp float g = dot(p.xyz, vec3(0.344, 0.5, 0.156));
                gl_FragColor = color;
            }";
    }
}
```

I get the same error, but with shaderEffect.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layer.effect` actually expects a `Component`, which is not an instance of an object, but the prototype of one. Even if you don't set a component explicitly, it is implicitly created for you.

And since you don't have a concrete object instance, there is no `id` parent to indirect child visibility you can utilize, which is why your second example doesn't work.

And `alias` only works for actual nested instances, which you don't have in your case, the child is created later rather than being nested in the root component, which is why the first example doesn't work.

What would work:

```
Item {
  id: root;
  property color colorBackground: Qt.rgba(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
  property color colorStroke: Qt.rgba(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
  layer.enabled: true;

  layer.effect: ShaderEffect {
    property color colorBackground: root.colorBackground;
    property color colorStroke: root.colorStroke;

    fragmentShader: "
            uniform lowp sampler2D source; // this item
            uniform lowp float qt_Opacity; // inherited opacity of this item
            uniform lowp vec4 colorBackground;
            varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
            void main() {
                lowp vec4 p = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0);
                lowp float g = dot(p.xyz, vec3(0.344, 0.5, 0.156));
                gl_FragColor = colorBackground;
            }";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that [`layer.effect` is of type `Component`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#layer.effect-prop).

[Components build their own scope](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-scope.html#component-scope). That means that the id `root` is only available by dynamic scoping.

[According to the documentation of property aliases:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-aliases)

> - It can only refer to an object, or the property of an object, that is within the scope of the type within which the alias is declared.
> - It cannot refer to objects declared outside of the scope of its type.

Thus it has to fail.